# SSIS Merge Join Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2014

I have a simple data flow.  I'm trying to join two sets of data from two different databases.  The `TXT` database is collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. The other dataset (`Cost`) is coming from Dynamics AX which is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

[image]

AX columns are Unicode.  So I have put data conversion on `TXT` columns to Unicode

[image]

However no matter what I do I cannot get rid of the `MERGE JOIN ERROR` and it's driving me insane.

> TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Both inputs of the transformation must contain at least one sorted column, and those columns must have matching metadata.

Both datasets are set to sort by `ITEMID` (and I have set sort keys in both).  Any ideas???

Comment: um why was this downvoted?  I have provided plenty of information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops my bad!  I was sure I had set the sort key on the advanced editor on ole db source but I hadn't!